# Can't boot after update, also can't reach grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, updates

I just updated my (single-boot) Ubuntu system today, and now I can't boot. Symptoms:

- If I just boot normally I get stuck on a screen with the laptop manufacturer's logo and the Ubuntu logo. I've left this for quite a while and nothing happens.
- If I tap ESC as the machine boots, I get a momentary flash of what looks like the GRUB menu and then immediately dropped in a command line. (Shift does nothing)
- Attempting most commands (e.g. "loadbios") in this command line gets me a "error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from" message.

Is this salvageable? I'd really really prefer not to have to format the drive and reinstall, as I've got stuff that I haven't backed up in a while on it.

Edit to answer questions that got asked:

- This is Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3
- I can boot from a USB bootable drive and get into a desktop environment with the "try Ubuntu" option
- However, if I try and reinstall Ubuntu, I don't get a "keep files" option.  [Options I get for installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQwQn.jpg)  Is this solvable, or do I have to manually move all of my important files onto an external drive?

Comment: You've not provided any product or release details; is this Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? what release? etc. Have you booted *live* media (eg. installation media and use the "Try Ubuntu") option to check everything looks okay. Your description sounds like all you're seeing is `plymouth` screen, but software stack details (ie. product/release details) are still helpful is advising on what to try next.  *FYI:  You can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without format, allowing you to correct many issues; not lose any data or your configs; but again we don't know what you're actually using*

Comment: I think it's Ubuntu Desktop, 18.something. Can't check for sure without being able to boot.  By "live media" do you mean making a USB bootable stick? I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: You said it was 18.something so your *live* media maybe a different release (you've now written 20.04 in your question which is a different product) or you have something else installed; you can peruse the system from the *live* media.   To install without format you use the "*Something else* option allowing you to keep data; but I'd check everything is good first & backup your data  first, as mistakes are easy to make & you've already changed details since you first asked the question... so be careful.  Wait for others to advise maybe (*I'm currently busy elsewhere*)

Comment: Did you install with UEFI Secure boot on? If not,then turning Secure Boot on in UEFI settings my prevent boot. And a UEFI update may have reset multiple settings & turn Secure Boot back on. Check your settings in UEFI.

Comment: I thought it was a Secure Boot problem - after I aborted the reinstall partway through and just tried booting normally one last time, I got asked to input the Secure Boot password and when I did so the machine booted normally. But the next time I restarted it I'm back to square one as in my original problem - hangs at the Ubuntu/manufacturer logo screen. I've disabled Secure Boot entirely, which hasn't helped. I can still reach a "Try Ubuntu" state from a USB.    Also I don't know where I got the 18 from, that was a guess because at the time I couldn't check. This whole thing has been 20.04.

Comment: Still need to know brand/model system and what video card/chip. Some need extra settings. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Acer Predator with some Nvidia RTX - don't think I can check the exact model number, "try Ubuntu" is just using the Intel graphics.  I already tried running boot-repair's default autofix mode.  The report is at paste.ubuntu.com/p/kCGzZ8jPfr

Comment: I've now managed to boot back into my main OS again. It remains to be seen if this is a permanent solution, but the change I made was to use recovery mode to remove "splash" from the GRUB configuration. I remembered this making a difference with a similar problem before - Nvidia cards don't seem to like the Ubuntu splash screen, and I guess the update re-enabled it for some reason?